# Bug in glibc `div()` code?

Tags: c++, c, implementation, glibc, integer-division

As quoted in "[Integer division rounding with negatives in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319880/integer-division-rounding-with-negatives-in-c)", in C before C99 (i.e. in C89) and in C++ before C++11 (i.e. in C++98 and C++03), for an integer division computation where either operand is negative the sign of the remainder (or equivalently, the rounding direction of the quotient) is *implementation-defined*.

Then comes the standard function [`std::div`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div) which is specified to *truncate the quotient towards zero* (i.e. the remainder has the same sign as the dividend (numerator)) (see for example [this answer to "what is purpose of div() library function?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11726016/688659)).

Here is glibc's code for `div()` ([source](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/div.c;h=44a30a7ea485a9eef38fb4ffe6aaebdc06468b3b;hb=HEAD)) (also quoted in "[Is div function useful (stdlib.h)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718217/is-div-function-useful-stdlib-h)"):

(Note: `div_t` is defined as:

```
typedef struct
  {
    int quot;
    int rem;
  } div_t;
```

-- end note.)

```
/* Return the `div_t' representation of NUMER over DENOM.  */
div_t
div (numer, denom)
     int numer, denom;
{
  div_t result;

  result.quot = numer / denom;
  result.rem = numer % denom;

  /* The ANSI standard says that |QUOT| <= |NUMER / DENOM|, where
     NUMER / DENOM is to be computed in infinite precision.  In
     other words, we should always truncate the quotient towards
     zero, never -infinity.  Machine division and remainer may
     work either way when one or both of NUMER or DENOM is
     negative.  If only one is negative and QUOT has been
     truncated towards -infinity, REM will have the same sign as
     DENOM and the opposite sign of NUMER; if both are negative
     and QUOT has been truncated towards -infinity, REM will be
     positive (will have the opposite sign of NUMER).  These are
     considered `wrong'.  If both are NUM and DENOM are positive,
     RESULT will always be positive.  This all boils down to: if
     NUMER >= 0, but REM < 0, we got the wrong answer.  In that
     case, to get the right answer, add 1 to QUOT and subtract
     DENOM from REM.  */

  if (numer >= 0 && result.rem < 0)
    {
      ++result.quot;
      result.rem -= denom;
    }

  return result;
}
```

As you can see there is a test after the big comment block, whose purpose is to "correct" the result if the built-in division truncates towards -infinity instead of towards zero.

Now the question:

***Isn't there a bug in that code?***

Let's first consider the example call `div(42, -5)`. "In math" **42/-5** is exactly **-8.4**, so theoretically in C89 and C++03 `42 / -5` could yield either `-8` (truncated) or `-9` (floored) depending on the implementation. Reading the code:

- If `42 / -5` yields `-8` then `42 % -5` yields `2` (as `42 == -8 * -5 + 2`), so the test is `(42 >= 0 && 2 < 0)` which is not true and the above function returns `-8` and `2`, as wanted;
- If `42 / -5` yields `-9` then `42 % -5` yields `-3` (as `42 == -9 * -5 + -3`), so the test is `(42 >= 0 && -3 < 0)` which *is* true, so the above function returns the "corrected" `-9 + 1` and `-3 - -5`, i.e. `-8` and `2`, as wanted.

But now let's consider the call `div(-42, 5)` (signs inverted):

- If `-42 / 5` yields `-8` then `-42 % 5` yields `-2` (as `-42 == -8 * 5 + -2`), so the test is `(-42 >= 0 && -2 < 0)` which is not true and the above function returns `-8` and `-2`, as wanted;
- If `-42 / 5` yields `-9` then `-42 % 5` yields `3` (as `-42 == -9 * 5 + 3`), so the test is `(-42 >= 0 && 3 < 0)` which... is *not* true! and the above function **returns `-9` and `3` instead of `-8` and `-2`**!

The comment in the code above first seems right when it says that the situation that needs a correction is when "REM has the opposite sign of NUMER", but then it makes the *huge simplification* "This all boils down to: if NUMER >= 0, but REM < 0, we got the wrong answer", which seems wrong (incomplete) to me because **it omits the case** "if NUMER < 0, but REM > 0" (`-42` and `3` in the previous example).

I can hardly believe that such a bug would have remained unnoticed since 1992 or 1990 (apparently [someone tried to "fix" it](http://minilib-c.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/stdlib/div.c) but it still seems incorrect because `div(-42, 5)` could return `-10` and `8`)... Arguably, most implementations have been truncating towards zero by default (and all are required to do so starting from C99 and C++11, so the issue is "moot" in the latest Standards <sup>1</sup>) so the bug wouldn't manifest on them, but still... Maybe I'm missing something here?

Thank you for any insights.

---

<sup>1</sup> *(Edit)* As for "the issue is moot in C++11 and C99 (and newer)": accordingly, in these Standards the built-in division is required to truncate towards zero, so we never need to adjust the result, but doesn't that then mean that the present implementation is *more complex than needed* and *unnecessarily inefficient*? The "big comment" is obsolete and the `if` test useless, so shouldn't that part just be removed entirely?

Comment: modulo operator with signed operands is implementation dependent.  I think that's the main crux of this issue.

Comment: @Jim `div`'s purpose is precisely to encapsulate the implementation-dependent operations to give implementation-_independent_ results. @ouah Your link is the same code as the last link in my question (http://minilib-c.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/stdlib/div.c) and as I said, for `num == -42` and `denom == 5` if you get `r.quot = -9` and `r.rem = 3`, the new "correction" `--r.quot` and `r.rem += 5` will give `r.quot == -10` and `r.rem == 8` (instead of `r.quot == -8` and `r.rem == -2`)...

Comment: I think they saw it another way.  They defined div precisely w.r.t. %, which they acknowledged was implementation dependent.  (Why do modulo operations with mixed sign operators anyway?  I don't think this was a heavily trod area, so there was little concern about consistency.

Comment: @ouah Yes, at least it tries to handle it :) the added correction looks more aimed at `-42/-5` which "could" give `9` and `3` instead of `8` and `-2` (Euclidean division) (but it's almost as far-fetched as imagining `42/5` giving `9` and `-3` instead of `8` and `2` (which is forbidden by the Standards anyway)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the original author of the code, I have to say: You're right.  It's broken.  We had no systems that behaved "the wrong way" for testing, and I probably wrote the above too late (or early...) in the day or something.

We're saved by the newer standards, and the entire thing should be cleaned out, maybe with a small `#ifdef` (and corrected adjustment code) for pre-C99 if necessary.

(Also I'll note that the original was not indented with GNU-style indentation :-) )

Comment: Chris Torek! That's _you_! Thank you so much for your answer! Really I couldn't hope for a better source :) (As for indentation, maybe the original was closer to this [div.c](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdlib/div.c?view=co)?) (Also, in the meantime I have been doing more web-searching, and found [another "fix"](http://www.beedub.com/Sprite093/src/lib/c/stdlib/div.c) (the XOR seems legit but the adjustment wrong), and especially **[a code from 1987](https://raw.github.com/7shi/minix-tools/master/lib/c/ansi/div.c)** (!) which seems to handle both 42/-5 _and_ -42/5 correctly!)

Comment: Yes, that's basically the original (K&R-ish, "high Bosticity" indentation :-) ... what eventually became style(9) in FreeBSD).  I never saw the Sprite version, nor the Vrije Universiteit one, before.  The xor seems risky with plain (signed) `int`.  The `static` method is valid, but in all cases the need for a run-time test just seems messy, somehow.  Even if we can't count on C99 it would be nice to have a compiler-specific #define describing integer divide behavior, since so many machines "behave the way C99 wants" in the first place.

Comment: Indeed. **I have filed a [glibc bug report](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15799).** (By the way, the Vrije Universiteit one was close, but e.g. on a machine that always floors the quotient towards -infinity, `div(-10, 5)`, which yields `{-2, 0}`, will be incorrectly "corrected" to `{-1, -5}`...)

Answer (score 0):

There's rationale, why it can't be implementation-defined and what must it be.

TLDR: remainder sign must match the division sign.

Rationale:
When recovering divided value, knowing divions result, remainder and divisor, it remainder has to be summed with divisor-division product. If remander flag is implementation-specific, than operation to sum it should be also implementation-specific, is not it? Or at least have a code, after division, which would fix remainder sign if it's incorrect.